# Can't find binary when using ENTRYPOINT on Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I am playing around with docker and this simple image

```
FROM golang:1.13.4-stretch

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

And when I try to run `docker build -t test . && docker run -it --rm test "go version"` I get the error `/bin/bash: go version: No such file or directory`

Without the ENTRYPOINT line I have no problem running it.

Also, it doesn't seem to matter which shell I use, as long as the line is there it will always fail.

Could anyone enlighten me does it behave like this?

FYI: The value of PATH inside the container when using the ENTRYPOINT doesn't include the /usr/local/go/bin (where the go exec is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the shell is interpreting `"go version"` as the command to run instead of the command `go` with the argument `version`. Try removing the quotes.

Comment: That did solve my problem, thank you John. I will need to investigate the effect of using quotes and not using them